# Loop Through All Child Elements of a Button in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have read multiple posts on how to loop through child elements. For some reason they do not work in my case. It only loops through the first level child.
I have a page with multiple buttons.
I want to click a button and get the title tags of each child element - not just the first level children.
At the moment, clicking the first button only outputs "div1". I want it to go through all children and output div1, span1, div2, div3.

```js
$(".mybut").on( "click", function(event) {
  $(this).children().each(function () {
    console.log(this.title); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='mybut' title='but1'>
  <div id="foo1" title="div1">
    <span id="span1" title="span1">Hello span 1</span>
    <div id='foo2' title='div2'>Hello 2
       <div id='foo3' title='div3'>Hello 3</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>

<button class='mybut' title='but2'>
  <div id="foo4" title="div4">
    <span id="span2" title="span2">Hello span 2</span>
    <div id='foo5' title='div5'>Hello 5
       <div id='foo3' title='div6'>Hello 6</div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're using `children()`, which as it's name implies, only retrieves the children of the target element.

As your goal is to look at all levels under the target, use `find()` instead. Also note that you need to provide a selector to this method, so `[title]` would make the most sense in this case:

```js
$('.mybut').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('[title]').each(function() {
    console.log(this.title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="mybut" title="but1">
  <div id="foo1" title="div1">
    <span id="span1" title="span1">Hello span 1</span>
    <div id="foo2" title="div2">Hello 2
       <div id="foo3" title="div3">Hello 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="mybut" title="but2">
  <div id="foo4" title="div4">
    <span id="span2" title="span2">Hello span 2</span>
    <div id="foo5" title="div5">Hello 5
       <div id="foo3" title="div6">Hello 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
```

Also note that I removed the additional unnecessary `</div>` in your HTML.

Comment: Seems to be another case of RTM